# Safari: SyntaxError: Use of reserved word 'class'

Tags: javascript, safari, ecmascript-6, mobile-safari, es6-class

I am trying to fit my website to all well known browsers
In all browsers my JavaScript code is working, but not in Safari.

I get next error in Safari: "SyntaxError: Use of reserved word 'class'"
[image]

[image]
my code is look like:

```
    class _MontInit {
    constructor() {}
    sendXMLHTTPRequest(url, data, method, callback, error) {
        var xmlHTTP = new XMLHttpRequest(); // new HttpRequest instance 
        xmlHTTP.open(method, url);
        xmlHTTP.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8');
        xmlHTTP.onload = callback;
        xmlHTTP.onerror = error;
        xmlHTTP.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
        xmlHTTP.send(data);
    }
}
```

The error placement is on class word before MontInit.
One of the solution over Web was to add "use strict". but it did not help.
Any ideas?

Comment: What version of Safari are you using?

Comment: I checked it on 5.1  and on 8, same issue

Comment: Those versions don't support `class`, check "Show all" at https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first version of Safari to [support ES6 Classes](http://caniuse.com/#search=class) was version 9.

You need to upgrade your browsers (or transpile the code to ES5).

Safari 5 hasn't had a security update since 2013. Safari 8 hasn't had a security update since 2015. I strongly advise taking the "upgrade" option.

Comment: Is there is any "shim" library  for such issues?

Comment: @AlexBerd — No. You need to add new language keywords, not API features.