# Safari browser reports error using classes in javascript

Tags: javascript, class, safari

I use a class in my javascript.

```
 class FileSet {
        constructor(id,
                    path,
                    folder,
                    children,
                    all,
                    isfolder
            ) {
        }
    }
```

It works in all browsers except Safari.
In Safari I get the following exception.
SyntaxError: Use of reserved word 'class'

How do I make my script run in Safari browser.

Thanks,
Gagan

Comment: Maybe this question might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44096182/safari-syntaxerror-use-of-reserved-word-class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be using safari browser less that version 9. The `class` keyword is a reserved keywork in ES6 and safari browser do not support ES6 less than version 9. So, you must need to update your browser to version 9 or more to get your JavaScript work.