Vanila Javascript Es6 Modules not working on Safari browser on Windows
I have a small code which works fine on Chrome, Opera, Edge and Firefox. But it's not working on Safari.
I am a windows user so I not that familiar with Safari in order to find out what is wrong.
I was using this website as reference but I am not sure if it's updated or if maybe i could have misunderstood something. But I guess it suppose to work.
https://caniuse.com/?search=javascript%20modules
I am using apache and php
I have 3 files (index.php > index.js > Entities/Contato.js)
Tried to let it as simple as possible but let me know if you need anything else.
Thanks
index.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<!-- This one works just fine -->
<script>
    console.log('init'); 
</script>

<!-- This one does not work -->
<script type="module" src="./js/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>

index.js
import {
ContatoEntity,
} from './Entities/Contato.js';

$(document).ready(()=>{   
Main.ContatoCreate();
})


class Main {    
static ContatoCreate(){
        let contatoCreate = new ContatoEntity();
        console.log(contatoCreate.getContatoId());
    }
}

Contato.js
class ContatoEntity{
    constructor(form) {
        this.form = form;
    }
    #contatoId='123';
    #contatoNome;
    #telefones = [];
    getContatoId(){
        return this.#contatoId;
    }
}
export {
    ContatoEntity,
}


Your problem cuase of ES6 syntax like class syntax so to fix it try to use something like vitejs.dev to transpile your code into old version of js

Are there errors in the JavaScript console?

@Joseph All modern browsers (including the latest versions of Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Edge, and Opera) support ES6 class syntax as well as module. Transpile is required only if you want to target older browsers (or for a few features that can't work without it).

"But it's not working" is not a good problem statement. What is this supposed to do, and what does it instead?

Hi guys, thanks for the replies. The problem is "nothing happens". No errors, no warnings, no messages. It suppose to show some messages(console.log) in the devTools but it does not show anything at all

Hi guys, thanks again. I was trying different approaches and when I change the code I found a first error and when I searched for this error I found this 2 links which could kind of explain what is happenning. The thing is Safari Windows had its last release in 2010
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44096182/safari-syntaxerror-use-of-reserved-word-class
https://support.apple.com/pt-br/102665
Thanks again
Gonna change it to solved now

thanks again. I was trying different approaches and when I change the code I found a first error and when I searched for this error I found this 2 links which could kind of explain what is happenning. The thing is Safari Windows had its last release in 2010
Safari: SyntaxError: Use of reserved word 'class'
(portuguese - but not but explanation about versinos and stuff)
https://support.apple.com/pt-br/102665
Thanks again Gonna change it to solved now
